# Build Cocoa Touch Framework with CocoaPod dependencies, don't embed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an SDK that I built into a **CocoaTouch Framework**.
This SDK uses CocoaPods, because it depends on some other libraries. I build the framework using this build script:

```
# 1
# Set bash script to exit immediately if any commands fail.
set -e
# 2
# Setup some constants for use later on.
FRAMEWORK_NAME="MyFrameworkName"
OUTPUT_DIR="${SRCROOT}/framework/build"
# 3
# If remnants from a previous build exist, delete them.
if [ -d "${OUTPUT_DIR}" ]; then
rm -rf "${OUTPUT_DIR}"
fi
# 4
# Build the framework for device and for simulator (using
# all needed architectures).
xcodebuild -workspace "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcworkspace" -scheme "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration Release -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphoneos" -derivedDataPath "${OUTPUT_DIR}"
xcodebuild -workspace "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcworkspace" -scheme "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration Release -arch x86_64 -arch i386 only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphonesimulator" -derivedDataPath "${OUTPUT_DIR}"
# 5
# Remove .framework file if exists from previous run.
if [ -d "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" ]; then
rm -rf "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
fi
# 6
# Copy the device version of framework.
cp -r "${OUTPUT_DIR}/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
# 7
# Replace the framework executable within the framework with
# a new version created by merging the device and simulator
# frameworks' executables with lipo.
lipo -create -output "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${OUTPUT_DIR}/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${OUTPUT_DIR}/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}"
# 8
# Copy the Swift module mappings for the simulator into the
# framework. The device mappings already exist from step 6.
cp -r "${OUTPUT_DIR}/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule"
```

This all works fine, also using the framework is not a problem. But since this framework is built using other dependencies, for example Alamofire and Firebase, there are traces of this in the `MyFrameworkName.framework`.

When I run an app that uses this my **framework**, and CocoaPods to add the needed dependencies to the project, I get these errors:

> objc[7299]: Class APMPBDynamicFilterResultTimestamp is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9966CA12-11F5-42FE-91FF-BB7A91C07571/MyProject.app/Frameworks/MyFrameworkName.framework/MyFrameworkName (0x101b34158) and /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9966CA12-11F5-42FE-91FF-BB7A91C07571/MyProject.app/MyProject (0x1007416e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

How would I go about building the framework with the dependencies (otherwise it won't build of course), but without including any of it in the framework?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using `Carthage` to build your framework? You could set the dependencies into the `Cartfile` and add them as needed

Comment: Unfortunately CocoaPods is a requirement, otherwise I would have switched a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact you are using cocoapods dependencies in your SDK. As you mentioned, everything works fine, until the host app has the same dependencies. Unfortunately, there is no simple way to fix the problem, due to symbols for the same dependencies were linked into both SDK and the app. However, there are a few approaches you might consider.

1. If you are willing to release your SDK through cocoapods, then you can specify dependencies in your podspec. However, in that case, the SDK should be built by cocoapods. e.g. [podspec example](https://github.com/Bluedot-Innovation/BluedotPointSDK-Salesforce-iOS/blob/master/BluedotPointSDK-Salesforce.podspec)
2. The other approach would be adding an abstraction layer to your SDK. You should use the [Bridge pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) to work with your abstraction.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you exactly mean with point 1? We are planning to make our SDK available through CocoaPods, but only those who we give access to our private repo containing the `.framework` file.
What do you mean by `the SDK should be built by CocoaPods`?

Wouldn't there be a way to built it without embedding it.

If I use a `.framework`, it has obviously been built while depending on Foundation/UIKit/etc. But this doesn't give conflicts. How would I achieve something like that, if possible?

Comment: I'll try to elaborate. When application integrates an SDK with dependencies, it's very important to have dependencies with the same version. Moreover, in some cases, they should be built with the same build toolchain. To achieve that, you can delay building your SDK during the application build stage. One of the options is using Cocoapods. In the sample podspec there are instructions to build an SDK from the source.  So, during the integration Cocoapods will ensure that the SDK and App both depend on the same dependencies and link them together. `Foundation/UIKit/etc` are system frameworks.

Comment: You mean the framework would be built on the user's machine when building the app that uses it? In this case it's important to keep the source closed/private. But did I understand it correctly?

Comment: yes, that's right. In that case, the framework will be built on the user's machine when building the app.

BTW, when you integrate you integrate Cocoapods with your SDK, do you use frameworks?